# Why do I need to drop to root to compile Cordova apps, which don't work?

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, emulation

I can't figure out why I can no longer build Android apps using Cordova on the same computer that I used to build the same apps that worked last month, after having updated Cordova and NodeJS.
Currently I'm having to utilize super user privileges to get as far as Cordova launching the emulator, but it is then unable to install the app on the emulator and subsequently crashes with the following error.
So first to root with

```
sudo -E su
```

Then the cordova command will launch the emulator without sudo

```
cordova emulate android
```

if I try cordova run android, I get nothing launching on the connected device. The following is the output after dropping to root then running the emulate command.

```
Running command: /home/lyndon/myapp/platforms/android/cordova/run --emulator
ANDROID_HOME=/home/lyndon/Software/android-sdk-linux
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin
WARNING : no emulator specified, defaulting to myavd
Waiting for emulator...
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered

Booting up emulator (this may take a while)...................BOOT COMPLETE
Running: /home/lyndon/myapp/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b /home/lyndon/myapp/platforms/android/build.gradle -PcdvBuildArch=arm -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.


/home/lyndon/myapp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: /home/lyndon/myapp/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/home/lyndon/myapp/platforms/android/build.gradle,-PcdvBuildArch=arm,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
Error: /home/lyndon/myapp/platforms/android/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:134:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
```

I never previously had to drop to root to launch the Android emulator with Cordova, why is this currently the case and why is the app not installing on the emulator?